# Sql server management

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created the employee table(which is dynamic) like below,

```
 Employee

 ID FirstName LastName EmailID PhoneNumber Address     IsActive
 1  A         X        A@X.com null        null         Y
 2  B         Y        null    12345       null         Y
 3  C         Z        null    null        null         Y  
 4  D         W        D@W.com 65432       DWAddress    Y
 5  E         U        U@E.com null        null         N
```

I want to calculate the total number of non nullable values in the column and calculate the percentage of the same.
For Ex:

```
Column Name : FirstName=> 
Total number of non nullable values=5 
Percentage : Total number of non nullable values/no of rows
             5/5*100=100

Column Name : LastName=> 
Total number of non nullable values=5 
Percentage :  Total number of non nullable values/no of rows
              5/5*100=100

Column Name : EmailID=> 
Total number of non nullable values=3 
Percentage :   Total number of non nullable values/no of rows
               3/5*100=60

Column Name : PhoneNumber=> 
Total number of non nullable values=2  
Percentage : Total number of non nullable values/no of rows
             2/5*100=40
```

To Achieve this , i created simple function GetTotalNumberOfRows(FirstName) and the query like below

```
  Select count(FirstName) from Employee
  where FirstName is not null and IsActive = 'Y'
```

This function returns the count of non nullable values based on the parameter.I used other query to get the total number of records in employee table.

```
  Select count(*) from employee
```

Finally am doing the calculation part

```
  Total number of non nullable values/no of rows
```

i am trying for single generic query instead of writing multiple queries and  passing the individual column name to
the function . i need a output like below

```
  ColumnName  TotalNonNullValues %
  FirstName   5                  100
  LastName    5                  100
  EmailID     3                   60
  PhoneNumber 2                   40
```

Can anyone suggest me how to write this in single generic query?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
DECLARE @totalRows int
Select @totalRows = COUNT(1) FROM Employee
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN FirstName is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) * 100)/@totalRows FirstName, (SUM(CASE WHEN Address is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) * 100)/@totalRows Address FROM Employee
```

Using Dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @colName nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @totalRows int
DECLARE @parameList as nvarchar(1000)
SET @parameList = N'@Rows int'
SET @colName = 'FirstName' --in ur case it will be from parameter
SELECT @totalRows = COUNT(1) FROM Hra
SET @query = N'SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN ' + @colName + N' is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) * 100)/@Rows ' + @colName + N' FROM Employee';
EXEC sp_executesql @query, @parameList, @Rows = @totalRows
```

Use the following query

```
SET @query = N'SELECT ''' + @colName + ''' + '' '' + CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN ' + @colName + N' is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as varchar) + '' '' + CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN ' + @colName + N' is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) * 100)/@Rows) as varchar) ' + @colName + N' FROM Employee';
```

Comment: here column name is hardcoded i want generic one because if i add any new column i dont want again to modify the sp

Comment: for that u can use the dynamic sql feature refer this..  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: is it possible to display all the column values like 
Columnname TotalnonnullValues %
FirstName      5                             100
EmailID          3                              60

Comment: Yes we can, see edited dynamic sql... also dont forget to make it as answer if correct.

Comment: but i need all the column names. pl see the ouput format in question

Answer (score 0):

You mean 'non null' not 'non nullable'.

You want something like this:

```
Select 
SUM(CASE WHEN EmailID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
/
COUNT(*)
* 100
as EmailID_Pct
from Employee
```

Comment: i don want to pass column name explicitly